# How should I read a file that is opened by some process?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm trying to read SAM.log but it's being opened by another process, thus notepad can't open it.

Any suggestion on how to read that file? I cannot reboot the server.

(The SAM.log is just an example I found on server)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the file is locked exclusively - you cannot access it until the process, holding the lock, terminates.

What you can do is try to schedule copying this file when that process terminates or server reboots.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of lock.
It it is locked exclusively nobody else can get at it.
If the lock still allows reading by others you can still copy it or open it with any tool that initially opens the file "read-only" and only switches to read-write when you modify it.

Is some rare cases it is possible that notepad won't open it but other tools can do it.
Notepad++ or the Lister/Viewer component of TotalCommander works quite well for this.

If you don't want to install 3rd party software on a server (or are not allowed to) you can put a portable app version of the tool on you home-drive.
Always there when you need it regardless with system you are on.